# Scala: issues using functions as first class objects

Tags: scala, function, contravariance

I need to have a collection of generic functions, but I can't get it done in the way I like.
I created a

```
List[(Any)=>Unit]
```

but as soon as I try to insert a function, for example a

```
String=>Unit
```

I get an error. How could I declare a generic function collection that does not consider parameter and return values types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to finish of `@Moritz`'s answer, you need to choose type argument for `T1` that is a subtype of the input type of every function in the list. `Nothing` fits the bill -- it is a subtype of every type.

```
scala> val l: List[Nothing => Any] = List((b: String) => b, (a: Int) => a)
l: List[(Nothing) => Any] = List(<function1>, <function1>)
```

An existential type also works:

```
scala> val l: List[_ => _] = List((b: String) => b, (a: Int) => a)        
l: List[Function1[_, _]] = List(<function1>, <function1>)
```

Comment: How would you call a function with the signature `(Nothing)=>Any`?

Comment: You can't, without a cast. But the question didn't call for that :)

Comment: Is there a way to get dynamically (Maybe through reflection) the actual type of the function, so that I can perform the cast?

Comment: At runtime, its the type parameters are erased, it's just a `def apply(v: AnyRef): AnyRef`.

Answer (score 11):

Functions are contravariant in the intput type parameters, e.g. in your case `Function1[-T1,+R]`. This means you can add an instance of `Any => Unit` to a `List[String => Unit]` but not the other way round. This of course makes sense as you cannot call a function expecting an argument of type `String` with an argument of type `Any`.